# WebAPI call using RestSharp gives status 404; WebRequest succeeds

Tags: c#, restsharp, webapi

I've got a section of code to do a call to an external webapi using WebRequest. I'm trying to update it to use RestSharp instead. What am I missing here to make the conversion? The closest question here to give any sort of idea what might be going on is found in [Calling webapi method gives 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16257537/calling-webapi-method-gives-404). The "answer" was a missing accepted content type. I've verified through the RestClient the types are present (and appear valid).

Common request JSON

```
  var statusRequest = @"
{
    ""auth"": {
        ""type"": ""basic""
    },
    ""requestId"": ""15"",
    ""method"": {
        ""name"": ""getStatus"",
        ""params"": {
            ""showAllStatus"": ""0""
        }
    }
}
";
```

WebRequest code

```
  var webRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://service.url/api/status") as HttpWebRequest;
  webRequest.Method = "POST";

  var username = "user";
  var password = "pass";
  var encoded = System.Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")
                                 .GetBytes(username + ":" + password));
  webRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);
  
  var requestWriter = new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream());
  
  webRequest.ContentType = "APPLICATION/JSON; CHARSET=UTF-8";
  requestWriter.Write(statusRequest);
  
  requestWriter.Close();
  
  var responseReader = new StreamReader(webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
  var responseData = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
  responseReader.Close();
```

Should convert to RestSharp as

```
  var client = new RestClient("https://service.url");
  client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("user", "pass");

  var request = new RestRequest("api/status", Method.Post);
  request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
  request.AddJsonBody(statusRequest);
  
  client.BuildUri(request);

  var response = await client.GetAsync(request);
```

EDIT: Make the RestRequest a POST

Comment: You are using GET instead of POST.

Comment: Good observation. Still a 404

Comment: I'm not talking about the RestRequest constructor, I'm talking about the call to `GetAsync`. Use `PostAsync`.

Comment: Oh wow. That's a derp moment. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the [docs](https://restsharp.dev/usage.html#request-body).

[image: warning in the documentation]

Also, you are calling `GetAsync`. Even if you set the request method to `Method.Post`, calling `GetAsync` will override it.

This will work:

```
var request = new RestRequest("api/status")
    .AddStringBody(statusRequest, DataFormat.Json);
var response = await client.PostAsync(request);
```